# How to document class properties in PHP 5 with phpDocumentor

Tags: php, class, phpdoc

Take in consideration the following PHP 5 class:

```
class SomeClass
{
    //I want to document this property...
    private $foo;


    function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function SetFoo($value)
    {
        $this->foo = $value;
    }

    public function GetFoo()
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }
}
```

How in [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/) will I document the $foo property? I'm not even sure it need to be documented but I would like to know how if if needs to...

I know how to document SetFoo() and GetFoo(), I'm just not sure about the private property (variable?).

Thanks!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
/**
 * This is what the variable does. The var line contains the type stored in this variable.
 * @var string
 */
private $foo;
```

Answer (score 19):

I would generally use at least the `@var` tag, to indicate the type of variable this is.

For instance :

```
/**
 * Some blah blah about what this is useful for
 * @var MyClass $foo
 */
```

This is exactly what's done by Zend Framework, for instance ; see [`Zend_Layout`](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Layout.php) *(quoting)* :

```
class Zend_Layout
{
    /**
     * Placeholder container for layout variables
     * @var Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Container
     */
    protected $_container;

    /**
     * Key used to store content from 'default' named response segment
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_contentKey = 'content';
```

Note : the `@access` tag was useful with PHP 4 *(when there were no `public`/`protected`/`private`)*, but I never use it when I document code written in PHP 5 : the code, using the visibility keywords is self-documenting.

Comment: @var MyClass $foo should actually be @property MyClass $foo, based on how you used it (and in that case, @property suggests a magic var). The Zend example that you posted does show proper usage of @var

Comment: Thanks for the detail about @access.  Thats exctly what I was looking for when I found this page.

Comment: +1 -- but should the name of the variable be in the comment in your first example?

Comment: the docblock that comes before a variable is the one that documents that variable ; so I would say that the variable's name is implicit *(but it might be useful to check how this behaves, just to be sure)*

Comment: Yeah.. I don't have PHPDocumentor available to test with right now; but I do point out that your second example from Zend Frameowkr doesn't have the names...

Comment: I don't use phpDocumentor at work, but I always put docblocks to help PHPStorm with auto-completion -- and I don't always put the variable name either.

Answer (score 7):

In the case you use a __get and __set magic methods you can use `@property`

```
/**
  * Description for the class
  * @property type $foo Description for foo
  * @property type $foo Description for bar
  */
 class SomeClass
 {
     private $foo;
     protected $bar;

     public function __get(){
         ...
     }

     public function __set(){
         ...
     }
 }
```

Links with more info:

- http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc/tags/property.html
- http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.property.pkg.html

Comment: `@property` is used to tag magic properties. To mark class members, use `@var`. See http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.property.pkg.html

Comment: In your example, `$foo` and `$bar` are no magic properties, because you declared them.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * docstring
 */
private $foo;
```

Important note: there should be **two** asterisks. Not one.